# R efficient way to use values as indexes

Tags: r, performance

I have 10M rows `matrix` with integer values

A row in this `matrix` can look as follows:

```
1 1 1 1 2
```

I need to transform the row above to the following vector:

```
4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Other example:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

To:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

How to do it efficiently in `R`
 ?

**Update:**
There is a function that does exactly what I need: `base::tabulate` (suggested here before)
but it is extremely slow (took at least 15 mins to go over my init matrix)

Comment: Welcome to SO @YevgenyM! You will be much more likely to get a helpful response if you include a sample of what you've tried in R.

Comment: Any specific reason your output vectors are of length 9?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, It is part of model which goes across all options (each vector in the matrix can contain any value in {1-9}) then I want to have Matrix of counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
m <- nrow(x)
n <- ncol(x)
i.idx <- seq_len(m)
j.idx <- seq_len(n)

out <- matrix(0L, m, max(x))

for (j in j.idx) {
   ij <- cbind(i.idx, x[, j])
   out[ij] <- out[ij] + 1L
}
```

A `for` loop might sound surprising for a question that asks for an efficient implementation. However, this solution is vectorized for a given column and only loops through five columns. This will be many, many times faster than looping over 10 million rows using `apply`.

Testing with:

```
n <- 1e7
m <- 5
x <- matrix(sample(1:9, n*m, T), n ,m)
```

this approach takes less than six seconds while a naive `t(apply(x, 1, tabulate, 9))` takes close to two minutes.

Comment: Indeed looks like much better solution than tabulate (especially that I have nbins=25 and not 9, which was provided just for the example)